# How to group the data by using email address and arrange it in ascending order based on the date & time?

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to group the data (as shown in the screenshot above) based on the email address and arrange it in ascending order based on the `Date & Time`. This is the expected output:

[image]

I tried to apply `Group by` on column B in `QUERY` function but it doesn't work. For `FILTER` function, I'm not sure how to populate the 2nd group data (`w@gmail.com`) based on the unique email as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Any helps and advice will be greatly appreciated!

### Edit

[image]

The formula in cell `K2` is `=SORT(FILTER(A2:G, B2:B=I2), 1, 1)`
The formula in cell `K3` is `=SORT(FILTER(A2:G, B2:B=I3), 1, 1)`

I'm not able to apply the formula to all the unique email in column I. It will cause error since the result is in array.

Comment: Ask this in [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, it makes no much sense to use the uniques because all rows will be returned anyway. If you want to "group" by name and then sort the dates ascendening you can try:

```
=query(A1:G, "where B <>'' order by B, A")
```

See if that helps?

Comment: Hi JPV, thanks for your reply. This formula unable to apply to entire unique email list in  column I. I edited my question with the problem that I faced.

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet. That makes it so much easier to help.

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HMmZsh5Cj21xr1YOPXY66ED_OLLLQP8S7C-rUcEerAs/edit#gid=0

Comment: Edited my answer. Also see the formula applied in your spreadsheet.